# Migrate SharePoint Site from 2013 to 2016

Tags: 2013, migration, 2016

Currently I'm trying to migrate SharePoint site from 2013 to 2016.

I have search on google but not found any article.
If any one know how to do this please suggest steps/articles.

Is that possible to migrate from SharePoint 2013 site to SharePoint 2016?

Comment: My best bet is that it's done like to 2013 - Attach database method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches for migration from 2013 to 2016.

1. Use 3rd party tools and migrate the data to 2016 farm. You have to build 2016 farm in advance.
2. Manual way.(database upgrade)

   - build a SharePoint 2016 farm
   - prepare the 2013 environment for migration( test the content db, clean the unwanted sites, doc etc)

     - move the database from 2013 stars server to 2016 square server
     - mount the database to sharepoint 2016
     - test it
3. You can use SharePoint PowerShell script to migrate as well the content if you don't have much customization

Comment: Actually I had never did this before.Will you please Explain Step by step. Or provide some related articles.

Comment: Steps are almost same as 2010 to 2013 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1105686/SharePoint-Migration-to @I-touch

Comment: That's sounds good..!!
let me try this.!

Comment: Waqas Sarwar MCSE, Red, Atish, I have done with the migration from SharePoint 2013 to 2016. Steps are almost same as 2010 to 2013.

Answer (score 3):

There are several technet articles here if this helps: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263026%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You need to create a new 2016 farm then move your content over.